# Add data attributes to the actual select options in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm populating a [select2](https://select2.org/) with options from an array and it almost works the way I want, but I'd like to add `data-attributes` to the actual option tags, in addition to just `value` and option `text`. How do I do it?

```
var categories =
[
    {
        id: 0,
        text:'Category',
        "data-type": 'global'
    }
];

$('select').select2({data:categories});
```

Comment: I think, you don't need the double quotes " for the data-* key in that object.

Comment: So `data-type: 'global'` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes

Comment: Yeah, but that's not in an array. Removing them gives me `missing : after property`

Comment: How do I open this thread up again? The answer submitted is to pass FROM options not TO options.

Comment: Just use, 
{
       type: 'global'
    } , don't need 'data-' in keys

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's still not adding them to the option tags though.

Comment: It adds id, text, selected, disabled but I haven't found a way for data attributes.